# Binding rvalue to non-const reference via pointer cast?

Tags: c++, reference, g++, rvalue

I don't understand how the following code compiles/doesn't compile:

```
struct Temp
{
  int i;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   //Temp &ref1 = (Temp){42}; // Error, as expected
   Temp &ref2 = *(Temp*)&(Temp){42}; // A-OK
   std::cerr << ref2.i << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.4.4.

Comment: Haven't done C++ often enough recently to remember if the core dump gives you useful info (like a stack trace).  Is there a way to provide that error message (maybe run under a debugger)?

Comment: This isn't pure C++ code, but it's GNU C++. It uses the C99 compound literal feature.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub- Thanks for pointing that out - I was rummaging through the spec trying to track down why that worked!

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham - Nevermind the comment about using a primitive, that was me being dumb about something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not really C++. It uses a compound literal which is a C99 feature. In C99 it evaluates to an lvalue and taking the address of the literal is completely fine there. Integrating this extension into C++, GCC appears to change the rule of it and make it an rvalue, better fitting the classification of them into the existing rules of C++ for usual casts that also produce rvalues.

GCC does not like `&(Temp){42}`, complaining that I take the address of a temporary. It's a warning about invalid code which it still accepts but does not really like. The same warning is given for other obviously-wrong code like `&A()`, which is a legal functional style C++ cast, which also produces an rvalue and thus cannot be used as the operand of the address-of operator.

The integration of compound literals into C++ by GCC also destroys the temporary prematurely, as can be seen by the following test

```
#include <iostream>
struct B {
  ~B() {
    std::cout << "~B" << std::endl;
  }
};
struct A { int i; B b; };

int main() {
  A *a = &(A){0};
  std::cout << "main" << std::endl;
}
```

In C99, the object that the literal refers to will be alive for the entire block (it will have automatic storage duration). In GNU C++ the object is destructed already at the end of the full expression, before the end of its block is even reached (the "~B" is printed before the "main").

Comment: What's interesting is that if I make 'a' a global, I no longer get the warning, which I imagine is because the literal is being given global scope and thus is lasting the length of the program. However if I change the 'int i' to a pointer and declare 'a' as `A *a = &(A){new int(0)};`, I will get the warning even at the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken about this, but this looks like a bug in the compiler.  The C++ ISO standard, §5.3.1/2, discusses the `&` operator as

> The result of the unary & operator is a pointer to its operand. **The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id.**

The section §5.4/1 discusses the casting operator as

> The result of the expression (T) *cast-expression* is of type `T`. The result is an lvalue if T is a reference type, **otherwise the result is an rvalue.**

This seems to suggest that

```
(Temp){42}
```

Produces an rvalue, which you should not be legally allowed to take the address of using `&`.

I've been known to make mistakes reading the spec before, so if someone could confirm this that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As templatetypedef has said, it does appear to be a bug in the compiler. When compiled with the 4.6.0 version of GCC, it gives:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

And, of course, with the addition of -fpermissive, it compiles but complains, but still it doesn't crash and prints the correct result. I guess GCC is cheating a bit under "permissive" conditions.